# SQLite date group/sort issue

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have ID's with timestamps d/m/y/t with a value linked to each ID. I'm looking to add up total value per day, from multiple ID's.

What I have so far is

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d', event_time) as valday,
sum(purchase_cost_usd) from iap
group by valday;
```

Issue with this is I am only getting the summed up purchase_cost_usd, not per day, and no list.

All help is greatly appreciated!

What I would like to have shown is the accumulated cost per day

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.